# Java: how to determine type of object in an array of objects?

Tags: java

Example:

```
Object[] x = new Object[2];
x[0] = 3; // integer
x[1] = "4"; // String
System.out.println(x[0].getClass().getSimpleName()); // prints "Integer"
System.out.println(x[1].getClass().getSimpleName()); // prints "String"
```

This makes me wonder: the first object element is an instance of class `Integer`? or is it a primitive data type `int`? There is a difference, right?

So if I want to determine the type of first element (is it an integer, double, string, etc), how to do that? Do I use `x[0].getClass().isInstance()`? (if yes, how?), or do I use something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the instanceof operator.

for instance:

```
if(x[0] instanceof Integer) {
 Integer anInt = (Integer)x[0];
 // do this
} else if(x[0] instanceof String) {
 String aString = (String)x[0];
 //do this
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between `int` and `Integer` and only an `Integer` can go into an `Object []` but autoboxing/unboxing makes it hard to pin it down.

Once you put your value in the array, it is converted to `Integer` and its origins are forgotten. Likewise, if you declare an `int []` and put an `Integer` into it, it is converted into an `int` on the spot and no trace of it ever having been an `Integer` is preserved.

Answer (score 6):

`x` is an object array - so it can't contain primitives, only objects, and therefore the first element is of type Integer. It becomes an Integer by autoboxing, as @biziclop said

To check the type of a variable, use `instanceof`:

```
if (x[0] instanceof Integer) 
   System.out.println(x[0] + " is of type Integer")
```

Answer (score 6):

not what you asked, but if anyone wants to determine the type of *allowed* objects in an array:

```
 Oject[] x = ...; // could be Object[], int[], Integer[], String[], Anything[]

 Class classT = x.getClass().getComponentType();
```